# use Access-Control-Allow-Origin with Ext.direct and JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, extjs, xmlhttprequest, ext-direct

I am creating a web application using Ext Js and java for connecting them I am using extdirect spring MVC, but as I want to access my java controller methods from Ext Js from different domain I have the following error `OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/hospital/ext/router?_dc=1370605013919 Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`, I search a lot but I could not find how to fix that problem for Ext js. If anyone knows please write me. 
Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 1):

The problem with java app.
Your app have to add CORS(Cross-origin resource sharing) headers for responses.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header of request allows call your service from all other domains.

Required headers can be added using http filters. The example for Spring:
http://zhentao-li.blogspot.com/2012/06/enable-cors-support-in-rest-services.html

Comment: This is great thank you but I have a little different method in java @ExtDirectMethod
 public String getSomething (){
  return "vasha";
 }

and I do not know how to add response header here in my method. Thank you